# Usar ISR en next js con react context?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, context

Estoy armando una landing page sencilla con next js y firebase. Los productos estan cargados en firebase y de ahi yo los cargo en el estado para mostrarlos.
El problema es que quiero usar el ISR de Next y me esta arrojando un error. Por lo que estuve averiguando creo que no se puede usar con el context pero no estoy seguro. Queria saber si estoy cometiendo algun error o si al usar context deberia hacerlo de otra forma

Se recibiria el "slug" del producto y en base a eso se muestra el producto con ese "slug"

```
interface Props {
    slug:Products
}

const ProductPage: NextPage<Props> = ({ slug }) => {

    

    return (
        <MainLayout title={``} pageDescription={''} imageFullUrl={''}>
            <Grid mt={7} display={'flex'} flexDirection={'row'} p={5}>
                <Card>
                    <CardMedia
                        component="img"
                        image={"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/segunda-floreria.appspot.com/o/bou90.jpg?alt=media&token=c520b370-9006-4e5a-9337-5145e84fb5ec"}
                    >
                    </CardMedia>
                </Card>
                <Box m={2} maxWidth={600}>
                    <Box>
                        <Typography component="h2" variant='h4' color="primary">Titulo del producto</Typography>
                        <Typography mt={3} fontSize={18}> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Magni, molestias. Atque animi distinctio aperiam ullam, nulla,
                            exercitationem, earum excepturi quam nostrum quia iste incidunt ea maiores
                            quibusdam aliquam repellendus placeat.
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography fontSize={20} mt={3} fontWeight="bolder">$90.000</Typography>
                    </Box>
                    <Box mt={3}>
                        <Button sx={{ textTransform: "capitalize", fontSize: 20 }} variant='outlined'>
                            Contactar
                        </Button>
                    </Box>
                </Box>
            </Grid>
        </MainLayout>
    )
}


export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async (ctx) => {
    
    const { products } = useContext(DbContext)
    const slug = products.map(product => product.slug)
    return {
        paths: slug.filter(slug => ({
            params: slug === slug
        })),
        fallback: "blocking"
    }
}




export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
    const { slug } = params as { slug: string }  

    if (!slug) {
        return {
            redirect: {
                destination: "/",
                permanent: false
            }
        }
    }  
    return {
        props: {
            slug
        },
        revalidate:86400
    }
}


export default ProductPage
```

Me sale el siguiente error: [image: error]

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Porque usas `DbContext` si no lo has definido antes?, se supone que `useContext` toma como parámetro otro contexto un objeto retornado por `createContext`.

Comment: A que te referis que no esta definido? @user327285

Comment: ¿Que versión de nextJS estas usando?

Comment: es la 13.4.10 @g.4

Comment: Chequeando la documentación para los contextos encuentro que debes usar `createContext`